# ts-node-esm throwing "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" without any error trace

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, ts-node

I want to run a single TS file that uses ES module imports (e.g. `import fs from "fs"`). I have done the following steps:

1. renamed the file from `myScript.ts` to `myScript.mts`
2. globally installed the latest version of `ts-node` via npm and created the npm script `"custom-script": "ts-node-esm ./myScript.mts"` in package.json
3. using the following tsconfig file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["@types/node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

4. run `npm run custom-script`

Now I get the following console output:

```
> ts-node-esm ./myScript.mts

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:141:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 custom-script: `ts-node-esm ./myScript.mts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 custom-script script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-02T19_08_42_558Z-debug.log
```

That's it. No useful stack trace. No line where the error originated from. Can't even open the files it shows in the trace because they're internal and VSC doesn't find them.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the error. I'm using an import assertion in the script file like this:

```
import CONFIG from "./config.json" assert { type: "json" }
```

This only works in newer versions of nodejs and I was using an older version.

What I still don't understand though is why ts-node didn't show this line in the error stack trace.